# foreach with sql select getting array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i work on my smarty script and i face some problems with my new php code..

i just need to hide videos that watched by Visitor based on ip, i try this..

```
 //-- Get visitor ip

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){   //check ip from share internet
        $visitor_ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){ //to check ip is pass from proxy
        $visitor_ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $visitor_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }//Get ip


if ( !empty ($visitor_ip) ){            
        $sql_query = "SELECT vid_id FROM videos_watched WHERE ip=(INET_ATON('$visitor_ip'))";
        $result_videos_watched = $GLOBALS["DB"]->result( $sql_query );
    }

        foreach ($result_videos_watched as $vid_id_watched){

            $videos_watched[] = $vid_id_watched;
        }


    $sql_query = "SELECT vid_id FROM videos WHERE mem_id=".$entry["mem_id"]." ".$GLOBALS["Videos"]->filter();


    foreach($videos_watched as $v_watched) {

        $sql_query.= " AND vid_id != ".$v_watched;
    }


    $sql_query.= " AND vid_id != ".$vid_id." ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 0,5";

    $result = $GLOBALS["DB"]->result( $sql_query );
```

I am getting a $v_watched = array !!

Thanks in advance

Comment: That makes sense with the code I see. What are you expecting?

Comment: If its an array, try `AND vid_id NOT IN (".implode(',',$v_watched).")";

Comment: SELECT vid_id FROM videos WHERE vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id != 112635 ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 0,5:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT IN () AND vid_id NOT ' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result_videos_watched` is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows of the results, and the second dimension is the columns. When you do:

```
foreach ($result_videos_watched as $vid_id_watched){
```

`$vid_id_watched` is one of the result rows, so it's an array of the columns. When you then do:

```
$videos_watched[] = $vid_id_watched;
```

You're setting an new element of `$videos_watched` to that array. So `videos_watched` becomes a 2-dimensional array (it's just a copy of `$result_videos_watched`). I think what you want to do is:

```
$videos_watched[] = $vid_id_watched['vid_id'];
```

As a suggestion, instead of making your new query have a series of `vid_id !=` tests, use `vid_id NOT IN (...)`. I expect that most SQL engines optimize that better.